# TFS in Visual Studio - How to get server repo to match local repo

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs, changeset

*Disclosure: Newbie with TFS and couldn't find useful SO answers*

---

A coworker submitted a bunch of changesets to source control -- Can I just get the most recent one to get all of his changes? Or would I need to get each one individually? In other words, do changesets compound?

And more generally, what's the easiest way to ensure my local repo is identical to the server repo (minus the new things I'm working on).

---

I'm much more familiar with Git if that would help explain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your source control set to TFS in VS (Tools > Options...) just right click on your project file in Solution Explorer and select Source Control > Get Latest Version (Recursive).  I do it twice just to make sure I get a message saying "up to date".

You can also use Source Control Explorer and get a specific changeset by right clicking the change set and selecting a similar option, and yes, these will get all changes up to the one you clicked.

Edit: 
A little confused rereading your title it sounds like you want the server to match local, then your question is about matching your local to the server.  So let me address both.

To get the server to match your local this would be most like a "Check in" (or 'push' in Git) this will merge your files into the server.  You can perform a check in by clicking the Team Explorer tab and selecting "Pending Changes" then type a description and click "Check In".  Where there are conflicts your will be notified and asked how to proceed, but in most cases following best practices this will not be the case.

Then you will want to match your local with the server (basically a 'pull' in Git) by right clicking the project file and selecting 'Get Latest Version (Recursive)'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob -- we've got some quirks with our site and TFS so Get Latest Version (Recursive) messes up some essential files, and we haven't figured out why yet. But that's great to know that selecting a recent changeset gets all the previous ones!

Comment: Good.  I felt I should modify my answer to better address the totality of your question, but I'm glad you found it useful.  We use TFS at my place of work and I use Git at home.  I'm more familiar with TFS than Git, but I hope my comparisons are helpful and not misleading.